# How can I use seek() in a binary file?

Tags: python, binary

I am creating a simple tool to edit some specific binary values, so I need to control the offset positions by using seek(), but instead of returning the hexadecimal value, it shows every value I type into the parentheses.
I am using a function for this, and it is activated by a command as soon as I open a file in Tkinter.

Here's how I did it:

```
def openFile():
    itaFile = filedialog.askopenfilename(
        filetypes=[("ITA Files", ".ITA"), ("All Files", "*")])
    itaOpened = open(itaFile, "rb+")
    itaOpened.read()
    a = itaOpened.seek(6)
    print(a)
    itaOpened.close()
```

I need it to return me this value at offset 06:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ICFPa.png

How can I solve it?
If I am not specific enough, please tell me so I'll be more detailed.

Comment: ```seek()``` only changes the position in the file - you still have to ```read()``` what's located at that position.

Comment: `seek()` returns the new file position, not the _file contents_ at that position.  After seeking, you need to `read()` to get the file contents.

Comment: Post the sample data as text here in the question. Its okay if its just that same represenstation that you show in the png, but will remain with the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`seek` changes the file postion but doesn't read anything. It wouldn't know in general how much to read. After the seek you can read 1 byte. As a side note, don't open with more rights than you need - no need to create an unnecessary failure point in your code.

```
def openFile():
    itaFile = filedialog.askopenfilename(
        filetypes=[("ITA Files", ".ITA"), ("All Files", "*")])
    with open(itaFile, "rb") as itaOpened:
        a = itaOpened.seek(6)
        a = itaOpened.read(1)
    print(a)
```